# Git question regarding merge - visual display of commits from branch distinctive from master

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge, branch

I am new to git and my oversee something. I am not sure how to desctibe my problem, but i will try it with few words.

When i go for changes on my modules/database/etc. i usually make a new branch. In the commits i explain, what i did. (Business as usual i think). But since i develop alone, there are no changes to the master after the branching.

When i merge the branch with the master, i loose track with the branch VISUALLY since they fall together. I usually add a dummy commit to the master before branching to make both stand out.

Is there a better way (best practice) to my "problem"?[image: Git commits shown in vs code using git graph extension]

One can´t see where "branch-from-master" started and where it ended. Making it hard to understand commit comments from time to time. 2nd branch was merged AFTER i added a dummy commit to master branch which makes the commit comments stand out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are issuing `git merge` without providing any options.

The default mode is `--ff` which fast-forwards (updates the branch pointer to match the merged branch) and doesn't create the merge commit when there were no changes to the "*master*" branch after you created "*branch-from-master*".

You could use `git merge --no-ff` to avoid fast-forward merges and create merge commits. This will make the history look the way you want it to be.

See https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/pull-request-merge-strategies-the-great-debate/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really some basic knowledge i am missing. The link was also very helpful. Sadly, i can´t find a way to configure this in vs code unless i am using gitlens.